# Spark not using partition information from Hive partitioned external table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I have a complex/nested Hive-External table which is created on top of HDFS (Files are in avro format). When I run the hive query it shows all records and partitions.

However when I use the same table in Spark:

```
val df =  spark
.read
.format("avro")
.load("avro_files")
.option("avroSchema", Schema.toString)
```

It does not show the partition column.

But,  when I use  `spark.sql("select * from hive_External_Table")`, it is fine and I can see it 
 in the created dataframe but the problem  is that I cannot manually pass the provided schema.

Please note, when I looked at the data, the partition column is not part of the underlying saved data, but I can see it when I query the table through Hive.I also can see the partition column when I try to load the avro files using pyspark:

```
df = ( sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").option("avroSchema", pegIndivSchema).load('avro_files'))
```

So I was wondering what it is like that?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the columns present in the `Schema.toString` value which you have used in the option schema part. It would be having the partition column missing.
Also try using the same schema you have used in the pyspark code.

```
option("avroSchema", pegIndivSchema)
```